# Why can't we have IoT from 2005? but begin now,or future?

Tags: digital-communications

In 2005,ITU announce the "IoT",but why can't we have IoT at that time?

Is it because the speed of internet is not fast enough?wireless communication is not good at that time?Does anyone have some good reason which can explain that we just have the IoT concept in 2005,but we can not have the IoT in the real world at that time?

Comment: Only product cost, and convincing people they wanted it.  I suspect that there were internet-enabled things in 2004; they just hadn't acquired a fancy three-letter name.

Comment: Concepts and standards come before the applications.

Answer (score 1):

IoT requires inexpensive low-power communication. There were no solution with those 3 characteristics in 2005. Also, it was harder to monetize data so the perception was that IoT would never payback.